# Digital Strokes

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Just woke up? Here's a puzzle to start your day!

*The **midpoint** of each linear segment is denoted by the letters A – G respectively.

[image]

**Answer:** FBECD|ADCG – CFBDE|DABEFG – ECDFB|EGAFCB – GC|GACD – FACDBG – CG|EABGCF – CDFEB|AGBFD

Examples of translating the obtained numbers into letters:

R – A – C – E – C – A – R = 23 – 6 – 8 – 10 – 8 – 6 – 23

A – N – S – W – E – R = 23 – 10 – 2 – 24 – 19 – 6

Once you solve this puzzle, you'll discover a word that can be used to describe this very puzzle itself! You'll also uncover the main reason why you probably shouldn't do this puzzle right after you wake up in the morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took me a while to parse the question, which is ironically appropriate, but the solution is:

> **TEDIOUS**

You need to

> Treat the letters A-G as individual parts of a seven segment display, giving the following numbers:
>  24 - 26 - 20 - 14 - 9 - 10 - 25
>  Then, from the examples, we can translate to letters by incrementing by 6 and reversing the order.